# Can I trim strings when I manage them to a DropDownList by DataSource?

Tags: c#, .net, string, drop-down-menu, trim

I have this code :

```
myObjects ps = new myObjects();

myDD.DataSource = ps;
myDD.DataTextField = "Title";
myDD.DataValueField = "ItemID";
myDD.DataBind();
```

that add a Text/Value pair values to a DropDownList.

I'd like to add these valus trimming it (so remove empty space first and in the end).

Is it possible on #C/.NET?

Comment: what kind of a data source is ps?

Comment: It's a normal Object (I've just updated my question)

Comment: I don't think it's what you're looking for, but a value converter can do what you want, assuming you're using WPF. You can find a simple example here: http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2009/08/15/so-what-s-a-silverlight-value-converter-anyway.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
myDD.DataSource = ps.Cast<YourItemType>().Select(i => new { 
                                                   Title = i.Title.Trim(),
                                                   ItemID = i.ItemID.Trim()});

myDD.DataTextField = "Title";
myDD.DataValueField = "ItemID";
myDD.DataBind();
```

if ps is a DataTable, you should be able to do

```
myDD.DataSource = ps.Cast<DataRow>().Select(i => new { 
                                                       Title = i["Title"].Trim(),
                                                       ItemID = i["ItemID"].Trim()});
myDD.DataTextField = "Title";
myDD.DataValueField = "ItemID";
myDD.DataBind();
```

Comment: Yeah. I can do it also on LINQ. Hoped in a faster way, but it's ok ;)